# How to store/generate an integer ID for every node or data in linkedList?

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I am working on a question, and decided to use linkedList to make it easy. I have create insertion at first, last and at position. **For now let's focus on insertion at first, this is what I want to achieve, whenever I insert a value into list I want to also store a unique ID along with it.**  So that when I want to search a particular item, I will simply use the ID and get want I am looking for. I am using JAVA  language here, and have created Node class for reference and LinkedList class that holds my functionalities. Note that the ID should be an int value say, if we insert very first item into list its ID should be "1" and so on..
Here, is my Node class :

```
public class Node {

    private int data;
    private int id;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int data, Node next, int id) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Node() {}

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And here is my insertAtFirst(int data) method :

```
public void insertAtFirst(int data) {

        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.setData(data);
        ID++;
        newNode.setId(ID);

        newNode.setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create private static value that is automatically assigned to each instance as the instance is created.  This works because the static source of the ID is the same for all `SomeNode` classes.

```
      String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
      List<SomeNode> list = new LinkedList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         list.add(new SomeNode(letters.substring(i,i+1)));
      }
      list.forEach(node->System.out.println(node.getInfo() + " " + node.getID()));


      class SomeNode {
         private static int ID = 1;
         private int id;
         String info;
         public SomeNode(String info) {
          this.info = info;
          this.id = ID++;
         }
         public int getID() {
          return id;
         }
         public String getInfo() {
          return info;
         }
      }
```

Note that if you are working with Threads this could be a problem as a duplicate ID could be assigned to two different instances. So you might want to look at the `Atomic` classes (e.g. `AtomicInteger`) as well as `synchronization`